# Is it appropriate to post question asking to prove NP-completness of more than one problem?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I believe that I discovered a method to generate several NP-complete problems. The NP-completeness proof is not immediately apparent to *me*. I did not find any reference in complexity literature to my problems and their $NP$-completeness. Such problems include the following posts:

[How hard is reconstructing a permutation from its differences sequence?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135968/how-hard-is-reconstructing-a-permutation-from-its-differences-sequence)

[Recognizing sequences sortable by transpositions?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27858/recognizing-sequences-sortable-by-transpositions)

> Is it fine to post question asking for proofs of $NP$-completeness of several problems?

Comment: I think you should consider posting questions about NP-completeness on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Upvoted since this is a reasonable question to ask; I have no specific opinion on the subject itself.

Comment: NP completeness is also on-topic here at MO.

Comment: Even if a question is on-topic in more than one site, choose just one site and ask it there.  Which site do you think is more likely to have experts that can contribute toward an answer?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Both sites have experts on computational complexity. Usually, I first post on TCS SE and offer a bounty. Then I post on mathOverflow if I did not get a satisfying answer. Sometimes, such as the first example above, a post generates more interest among mathOverflow members.